# Permutation of arguments of product of functions

Tags: combinatorics

Given a function, g, which is symmetric in its argument, g(a,b)=g(b,a), consider the product g(a,b)*g(c,d)*g(e,f). I would like to get all the permutations of this product with respect to the arguments, that is, terms such as g(a,c)*g(b,d)*g(e,f), which respect the symmetry so that g(c,a)*g(b,d)*g(e,f) would not be among the generated terms.  Is there a way to get Mathematica to do this?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: g(a,b)^3 counts?

Comment: That's a good question by @Kuba, my answer supposes we cannot reuse elements.

Comment: Since I don't know what exactly we are looking for, I'm just going to leave here this comment :) `Times @@@ Apply[g, Tuples[Subsets[l, {2}], 3], {2}]`, where `l = {a, b, c, d, e, f}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with four variables instead of six but the same would work for six. The strategy is to find a list of suitable permutations of possible arguments and then apply that to a helper function that encapsulates the product you're looking for.

```
h[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_] := g[a1, a2] g[a3, a4];
permutations = 
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Permutations[{a1, a2, a3, a4}], (#[[1 ;; 2]] == #2[[1 ;; 2]] || #[[1 ;; 2]] == 
       Reverse[#2[[1 ;; 2]]]) && (#[[3 ;; 4]] == #2[[3 ;; 
          4]] || #[[3 ;; 4]] == Reverse[#2[[3 ;; 4]]]) &];
DeleteDuplicates[h @@ # & /@ permutations]
```

> `{g[a1, a2] g[a3, a4], g[a1, a3] g[a2, a4], g[a1, a4] g[a2, a3]}`

After thinking for a while I also came up with this method, which is a bit prettier:

```
Clear[h,g]; SetAttributes[g, Orderless]
h[{a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_}] := g[a1, a2] g[a3, a4]
DeleteDuplicates[h /@ Permutations[{a1, a2, a3, a4}]]
```

> `{g[a1, a2] g[a3, a4], g[a1, a3] g[a2, a4], g[a1, a4] g[a2, a3]}`